# Issues with USB External Keyboard connected to Lenovo Thinkpad T480s through Lenovo USB-C Dock 2nd Gen

Tags: release-hera, keyboard, usb, thinkpad

I installed Elementary OS 5.1 Hera on my Lenovo T480s Laptop and almost everything works smoothly. However, I am experiencing a minor (but annoying) issue with the docking station.

At the start-up, the USB External Keyboard connected to the docking station perfectly works, whereas it stops working every time the laptop wakes up from standby, and rebooting is required to restore the keyboard's functioning. Other than that, the two external displays connected to the same docking station through DisplayPort work just fine in all the situations, as well as the USB ports.

Have you experienced anything similar? Is it a bug?

Thank you.